# why vector does not updates in loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to update vector 'v' so that I can iterate from count 0-100.

I know this is not allowed, but what if I want to do this only?
Is there any way?

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    int count = 0;

    for(int elem: v){
        if(count<100)
        v.push_back(count);
        count++;
    }

    for(int elem: v)
    cout << elem << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1    
0
```

Comment: The output from the code is expected. I don't understand what you are trying to do. `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` ?

Comment: @NeilKirk he think that the lenght of v in for(int elem: v) will be updated

Comment: @Thomas Oh I see, I didn't spot that!

Comment: This is a particularly obscure way to code things. I hope this was just an example and not something you do regularly.

Comment: `push_back` invalidates all iterators on reallocation and invalidates the past-the-end iterator in all cases. Your code has UB because under the covers the range-for increments a potentially invalidated iterator and then compares it to a definitely invalidated iterator.

Comment: @T.C. I think it should be an answer (assuming this is OP's real problem, and they didn't just want a way to fill a vector with 0..100). edit: user2079303 added it to their answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see from the [definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) of the range-based for loop, the *end_expr* does not update between iterations. Therefore you only have one iteration. `push_back` invalidates `v.end()` (which is what *end_expr* is as described in the linked page), so what you have is actually undefined behaviour.

The arguably simplest way to fill vector with 0..100 would be:

```
vector<int> v(101);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Comment: You want `(101)`, not `{101}`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use this code instead

```
int count = 0;
while (v.size() < 100) {
   v.push_back(count++)
}
```

Modifying vector while iterate through it is not allowed

Comment: _"I know this is not allowed but what if i want to do this only ??"_

Comment: for(int elem: v){
        cout << elem << endl;
        if(count<100)
        v.push_back(count);
        count++;
    }
if loop is like this ? @nnesterov

Comment: thanks guys, and i dont know indent in comment section :( sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

using your code :

```
for(int elem: v){
    if(count<100)
        v.push_back(count);
    count++;
}
```

is like using this :

```
int i = v.size();
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
     v.push_back(j);
}
```

I don't really know why... v.size() might be keep in memory for optimization and data protection

Edit after OP comment :

Try this

```
int i = v.size();
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
    if(j<100)
        i = v.size();
    v.push_back(count);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `v.size()`?

Comment: It will use `iterator` and not index, (and so lead to UB).

Comment: guys i was looking for some way so that i can change vector's length in for loop so that i can point to newly inserted value but i know it is not allowed :), nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Best efective way for this operation

```
vector<int> v;
v.resize(100);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    v[i] = i;
}
```

same as above.

Comment: "Best effective" in terms of what?

Comment: the push_back method is coercive so we can set the size of vector firstly than ve assign the values. and i think iota didn't have before c++ 11? am i right? so if you use old version c++ you cant use iota.

Answer (score 2):

A [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) produces code similar to this:

```
{
auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr,__end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
  } 
}
```

As you can see the range will not be updated as you're iterating over your container.

Additionally you're most likely ending up with undefined behaviour because as you're [pushing back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) values to your `vector` these iterators will be invalidated in case of a resize.

See @user2079303 for a better way to fill your `vector`.

Comment: actually my intention is not to fill vector like that, rather i wanted to know is there any way to update vector range in loops?

Comment: I don't really think it would be a good idea to the range from within the loop even if it was possible. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I thought of inserting elements in vector and simultaneously iterate it, its not posible in vector but in std::list , was just trying that stackoverflow can find some way or not :p